Error when redeploying Azure Spring Apps with "reading 'minReplicas"
I previously deployed my spring boot project on Azure successfully with the following application.properties, but now I am receiving an error message:
`Failed to deploy app diamondstore
(1/3) Requesting file upload URL... Done 
(2/3) Uploading JAR package... Done 
(3/3) Deploying with new JAR package... 
Failed Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'minReplicas')`

I'm not sure why this is happening, since I am still using the same application.properties file as before,** build project successfull ** and have .jar file as before. Here is what it looks like:
# server
spring.application.name=diamondStore
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://diamondstore.database.windows.net:1433;database=DiamondStore;user=;password=;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2019Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = none
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl

# email properties
spring.mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.port=587
spring.mail.username=
spring.mail.password=

# SMTP authentication
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true

# STARTTLS encryption
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true

But it just error when I redeploy a Azure Spring App. If I create a new one and provide my .jar file for the first time, it work successfull.
I also check Scales Up and Out of my Azure Spring App and it have setting like this :


I have tried many ways and searched everywhere but I see no one has the same problem as I do now.

Try deploying using mvn azure-spring-apps:deploy, refer SO answer.
